# Error "version" not found after adding bert as a submodule to my git repo

Tags: git, git-submodules, bert-language-model

After adding BERT as a submodule, cannot use it, the version info is missing in the config file. These are the main steps:

1- I've used the `git submodule add https://huggingface.co/bert-base-multilingual-uncased` command to add it as a submodule to my repos
2- I've put it in a directory whose name is: `pretrained/mbert/`
3- I've used the following code to use it:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer


def embed_text(sentences, pretrained="../pretrained/mbert/bert-base-multilingual-cased"): 
    """
    Computes the embeddings of the different sentences in input.
    :param sentences: list, of sentences
    :param pretrained: str, the pretrained bert model
    :return: list, of list
    """

    model = SentenceTransformer(pretrained) 
    sentence_embeddings = model.encode(sentences)

    return [arr.tolist() for arr in sentence_embeddings]
```

I've got the following error:

```
model = SentenceTransformer(pretrained)  
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sentence_transformers\SentenceTransformer.py", line 104, in __init__
    if config['__version__'] > __version__:
KeyError: '__version__'
```

Comment: I got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That cannot directly be used, the model download from huggingface.co. See this [issue](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/issues/184), the model folder frameworks are different between the trained PTM using transformer and trained ones using sentence-transformer.

For PTM trained using sentence-transformer,

> The folder should consist these files:
> 0_Transformer/
> 1_Pooling/
> config.json
> modules.json